# How to auto refresh different result in different divs on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, combobox

I have combobox and by clicking on the combox selection it shows the result in a particular `<div>` using JS Code and on the same page where the result is shown, by default on opening the page the records are shown.

I am refreshing the default result by using JS Code and it is refreshing it. but when i select the combobox it shows up the result but after showing on refresh after xx seconds for default div it refreshs the combobox selection result it goes back to default result.

How i can make it that if i select the combobox item then it will show the different divs and refresh the the combobox selection result and if default result is there then it will refresh the default result.

Any help will be appreciated.

my code is as below:

**ComboBox:**

```
<form id="search_forms">
    <?php
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('lepetit', $dbLink);
    ?>
<select id="selectFilter" class="sort_rangs" name="cuisine[]">
    <?php
    $atrias = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM cuisines");
    while ($trias = mysql_fetch_assoc($atrias)) {
    $temp[] = $trias['id'];
    $thelist    =   implode(",",$temp);
    }
    ?>
<option id="all" value="0,<?php echo $thelist; ?>">Select....</option>
    <?php
    $tris = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cuisines");
    while ($trys    = mysql_fetch_array($tris)){
    ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $trys['ename']; ?>" value="<?php echo $trys['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $trys['ename']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

**Refresh Code for Default Result**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#open').load('restaurants_main_big_site.php');
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Refresh Code for Combobox Result**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#cuis').load('ajax_searchsC.php');
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Div's For Default and combobox results:**

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if(isset($cuisine)) {
?>
<div class="ajax_resultT row check"> <!-- Div For Combobox Result -->   
<div id="cuis" > <!-- Refresh For Combobox Result -->
</div></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="ajax_result row check"> <!-- Div For Default Records -->    
<div id="open" > <!-- Refresh For Default Records Shown --> 
</div></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**JS code for processing the ComboBox Form:**

```
$(document).on('change','.sort_rangs',function(){
   var url = "ajax_searchsC.php";
   var wasExecuted;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $("#search_forms").serialize(),
     success: function(data)
     {
     $('.ajax_resultT').html(data);        
     }  
     }               
   });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you try make the question a bit clearer, maybe try rewriting it again a little differently. Maybe detail what you want to happen in numbered points. It's just tricky following the whole paragraph.

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini you have a long paragraph with 3 sentences, it's not easy to read.

Comment: Possibly change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`   In "Refresh Code for Default Result" you tell the page to refresh the default ever 1 second - so if you change it, 1 second later it will go back to the default.  But it's hard to see from the text+code what it's trying to do vs what you want it to do vs what it's actually doing.

Comment: @freedomn-m after changing it to `setTimeout` it stopped going back to default result but it stopped updating the part of div what i want to keep updating. There is open and close button on every restaurant when the time is finished it will show closed and when open it will show open.

Comment: Then you need to separate your "default" reload and the "combox" reloads.  Or add a data attribute to the div to say if it's affected by the combo option or should reset.

Comment: @freedomn-m can u help me, make and post it here?